# Numpy create grid of indicies?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a matrix in which each row contains the 2D coordinates of a grid. I can get the x-coordinates and y-coordinates using np.meshgrid as follows:

```
aa = np.arange(6)
bb = np.arange(3)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(aa,bb)
```

but how can I combine each corresponding entry to merge the 2 coordinates into one entry in a 2d numpy array(matrix)?

Comment: For this special case `np.indices((3,6)).transpose(1,2,0)`. Please include the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot end up with a 2D matrix since xx and yy are 2D matrices already. You can generate a 3D matrix. you could used `np.stack`

```
import numpy as np

aa = np.arange(6)
bb = np.arange(3)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(aa,bb)
yx = np.stack((yy,xx ),axis=2)
print(yx[0,1,:])
```

Comment: good answer. Probably would be `yx = np.stack((yy, xx),axis=2)` for matrices line first order

Comment: Thanks! But shouldn't there be a way to get a matrix that contains its own index in each of its entries for the corresponding indicies?

Comment: For example, this matrix has xy[0,1,:]=[1,0] which seems reversed to me

Comment: As said bu @YScharf, we can reverse xx and yy. I edited the post